# Parsing UTC time to CET/CEST

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, utc, dst

The data I fetch from DB is in UTC time. I need to convert it to CET/CEST. I am using below code. I am not sure if both CET and CEST will be taken care of. Please let me know if it takes care of CET and CEST ?

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    return LocalDateTime.parse(ptu, formatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"))
            .format(formatter);
```

Comment: Could you not test with a CET date and a CEST date?

Comment: Rather than getting a string from the database and parsing it into a `LocalDateTime`, why not fetch a `LocalDateTime` from the outset? `yourResultSet.getObject(yourColumn, LocalDateTime.class)`.

Comment: With all of the time zone changes that happen all over the world, Don't think of "CET/CEST" and instead think of "the time in Amsterdam", or wherever you happen to be talking about.  One can't make the assumption that the time in Amsterdam is the exact same for other places using similar abbreviations for all points in time.  In fact, it's likely that many dates are quite different between these various locations.

Answer (score 0):

CET and CEST are not always the same, so you can't guarantee that one result will satisfy both timezones.

Consider using [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for your example

Printing the time now, and in "CET" is straightforward:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now();
System.out.println(odt); // 2018-10-26T11:25:49.215+01:00
System.out.println(odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("CET"))); // 2018-10-26T12:25:49.215+02:00[CET]
```

However, I don't believe there is a "CEST" in the `ZoneID` class.

So you could print the time of a particular country you know is in CEST and compare them.

For example, Algiers is currently in CET, but Amsterdam is in CEST:

```
System.out.println(odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")));
System.out.println(odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Africa/Algiers")));
```

Output:

> 2018-10-26T12:42:29.897+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
>
> 2018-10-26T11:42:29.897+01:00[Africa/Algiers]

Answer (score 0):

The class you should be using is [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html); as it has full time-zone support(including daylight savings).

Your code should be replaced with:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
ZonedDateTime utcTime = LocalDateTime.parse(ptu,formatter).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime yourTime = utcTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));

return yourTime.format(formatter);
```

Comment: The asker is already using `ZonedDateTime `. The code in the question is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer below snippet :

```
            ZonedDateTime dateTime =null;
            Date finalDate = null;
            DateTimeFormatter format =null;
            String date = yourdate;
            LocalDateTime lid = LocalDateTime.parse(date, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(""yyyy-MM-dd"));
            ZoneId id = ZoneId.of("GMT");//Add yours
            ZonedDateTime gmtZonedDateTime = lid.atZone(id);
            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"); //in case your add your
            dateTime = gmtZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(id);
            format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SimpleDateFormat sfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            finalDate = sfmt.parse(format.format(dateTime));
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.